# DLLImport attribute PInvokeStackImbalance error

Tags: .net, pinvoke, dllimport

I am attempting to call an unmanaged dll from vb (VS2013 Express) using the dllImport attribute as follows:

```
<DllImport("armdll32.dll", setlasterror:=True, charset:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Public Shared Function ArmConnect(ByVal port As Integer, ByVal baud As Long, ByRef   serialNumber As String) As Integer

End Function
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
Dim serialNumber As String = ""

Debug.WriteLine(MicroScribeWrapper.ArmConnect(0, 0, serialNumber))
```

but I get the following error:

*Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'C:\XXXX'
Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'MicroscribeSDKTest!MicroscribeSDKTest.MicroScribeWrapper::ArmConnect' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.*

The documentation from the dll help file describes the function as follows:

*ArmConnect detects and establishes a connection to a MicroScribe. ArmDll32/ArmDll64 will connect to the first MicroScribe device it discovers. Detection order is as follows:
scan all USB ports at all times; 
if called with port=0 and baud=0, scan all available serial (COM) ports and try to connect at 115200 bauds; else, scan desired serial port at desired baud rate. 
The port number and baud rate parameters are ignored if a MicroScribe is discovered on a USB port. When using USB connections, it is sometimes desirable to connect more than one MicroScribe unit to the host computer. In applications as such, each unique unit connected can be identified by its serial number string, passed by the optional parameter serialNumber. When using this configuration, separate instances of ArmDLL need to be running for each MicroScribe unit.*

```
        int ArmConnect ( int port, long baud, char *serialNumber = 0 );
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem has to do with how I am calling the ArmConnect method but everything I've tried to date has failed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `ByRef serialNumber As String` replace with `ByVal` `baud As Long` replace with `Integer`

Comment: ensure the CallingConvention too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see a few problems here.

- In C++ on Windows, `long` is 32 bit. So the `baud` parameter in your p/invoke should be `Integer`.
- The string parameter `serialNumber` is presumably a C string. That is pointer to null-terminated string. That would be `ByVal serialNumber As String` in the p/invoke.
- Finally the calling convention. As written, it would seem that the unmanaged code uses the cdecl calling convention. Your p/invoke uses stdcall. It is possible I suppose that the calling convention of the unmanaged code is in fact stdcall, and the documentation you have included omits that. A read of the library's header file would clear that up.
- I think it unlikely that the function returns errors by calling `SetLastError`.

So, in summary, the p/invoke should be

```
<DllImport("armdll32.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, _
    CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Public Shared Function ArmConnect( _
    ByVal port As Integer, _
    ByVal baud As Integer, _
    ByVal serialNumber As String _
) As Integer
End Function
```

or

```
<DllImport("armdll32.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Stdcall, _
    CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Public Shared Function ArmConnect( _
    ByVal port As Integer, _
    ByVal baud As Integer, _
    ByVal serialNumber As String _
) As Integer
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you David. I looked at the header file as you suggested and it turns out there is an ArmConnectSN as well as ArmConnect. The first uses the serialNumber argument, the second does not. That, in combination with your other suggestions, appears to have things working. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. This is my first question and I didn't realize how I needed to close it out.